# UTF-8 encoding with Spring Boot 1.1.1

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, spring-boot

How can I "say" Spring Boot to use the UTF-8 encoding, to show and save German umlauts correctly?
We are programming a Java-Webapplication using Sping-Boot 1.1.1 (Release) and as webserver a TomCat7 or Jetty. The database is postgresql or h2 for testing.

Edit:

I tried it with the properties file (thanks for the answer), but no changes are visible.

The database is also UTF-8...
Especially the problem comes, when we send a POST-Request to the Webserver.
The Spring-Request-Handler gets already the broken encoded values.
In the following you can see a part of the code:
(It shows a snippet of the Thymeleaf-Template)

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset th:object="${model}">
                <!-- CSRF token -->
                <th:block th:replace="makros :: csrf" />
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group" >
                    <label for="firstname" th:text="#{edit_user.first_name}">Given Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control required" type="text" required="required" id="firstname" name="firstname" th:field="*{firstName}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <label for="firstname" th:text="#{edit_user.last_name}">Family Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control required" type="text" required="required" id="lastname" name="lastname" th:field="*{lastName}" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
 </form>
```

And this is the request handler for that:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleUserUpdate(@ModelAttribute(MODEL) UpdateUserCommand command) {
   //here we cut the broken encoded values
}
```

Greetings
Stef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrongly encoded? The request or the response? `server.tomcat.uri-encoding` is switching the **URI** decoding to `UTF-8` (this is already the case for Jetty).

But that does not do anything for the request body. By default, Spring MVC decodes that with `ISO-8859-1` (that is the default per the servlet spec). You need to specify a body encoding in your request if you want it to be decoded using `UTF-8`. Most users are actually using the `CharacterEncodingFilter` to achieve the same thing (and ensure consistency).

If that fixes your issue, watch out for [#1182](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1182) that is meant to provide an auto-configuration for that.

Answer (score 5):

This helped:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/securitydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Both this *and* `server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8` worked. One to prevent corruption in the DB and one to prevent corruption when submitting UTF.

Answer (score 2):

The latest should be UTF-8 by default I think? See docs on `server.tomcat.uri-encoding`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties. OTOH it might depend on where you need the encoding to happen (Spring Boot knows nothing about your database server encoding for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can set UTF-8 as default encoding for spring-boot-maven-plugin.
I create 2 maven profile to run spring boot in UTF-8 and set active spring profile via maven profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"</jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And run

`mvn spring-boot:run` for dev profile (application-dev.properties) and

`mvn -P prod spring-boot:run` for application.properties